# MySQL join query for 2 tables: incorrect return

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, right-join

I tried to search posts, without any result either, maybe I didn't use the right words.

I need a solution in MySQL (5.5.62).

I have two tables

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| Ln         | Ln1      | Cn            |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| 17149      | E.W.T.N. | 1400-1-385171 |
| 24210      | C.A.T.R. | 1400-1-385171 |
+------------+----------+---------------+
2 rows in set


+---------------+------------+-----------+
| Nm            | Ln         | Ln1       |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| 1400-1-385171 | 35955      | C.E.S.N.  |
| 1400-1-385171 | 35955      | C.E.S.N.  |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set
```

I need do a select it will return

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| Ln         | Ln1      | Cn            |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| 17149      | E.W.T.N. | 1400-1-385171 |
| 24210      | C.A.T.R. | 1400-1-385171 |
| 35955      | C.E.S.N. | 1400-1-385171 |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

I have try this query

```
mysql> SELECT
    Ln,
    Ln1,
    Cn
FROM
    `tbl_1` t
JOIN `tbl_2` m ON t.Cn= m.Nm
WHERE
    Cn IN ('1400-1-385171')
GROUP BY
    Ln
ORDER BY
    Ln ASC;
```

But the return is

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| Ln         | Ln1      | Cn            |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| 17149      | E.W.T.N. | 1400-1-385171 |
| 24210      | C.A.T.R. | 1400-1-385171 |
+------------+----------+---------------+
2 rows in set
```

How to do resolve this?

Comment: You should read a SQL tutorial to learn the difference between `JOIN` and `UNION`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to `UNION` the two result sets into one:

```
SELECT  Ln,
        Ln1,
        Cn
  FROM  `tbl_1`
UNION
SELECT  Ln,
        Ln1,
        Nm
  FROM  `tbl_2`;
```

`UNION` joins both result sets together as if they were a single table.  This combines results from both tables.

Using `UNION` as opposed to `UNION ALL` will cause exact duplicates to be removed from the combined result set.

More information about how to use `UNION` is in the official docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html).

Comment: You might want to add a bit about how `JOIN` essentially adds the 2nd table as columns to the first table, rather than rows. Otherwise you're spot on.